# Why is AWS Daily Mobile Push not working when Immediate does work?

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-mobilehub, aws-pinpoint

The AWS docs for Pinpoint Mobile Push imply that to shift from a working 'Immediate' to a 'Daily' delivery is a simple change on the campaign options.  But, with 100% success rate for the 74 current endpoints, it shifts from a high delivery rate to a zero rate when the 'Daily' option is selected.

There doesn't seem to be any other options needed to shift from Immediate Push Notifications to Daily.  I've also posted this on AWS forums, but haven't yet found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are hitting the maxiumum number of messages a user can receive per day?

> Maximum number of messages a user can receive per day – The number of messages that each campaign for the app can send to each user daily.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/settings-project.html

---

I would test whether or not a device of yours is getting the notification from the "Daily" campaign. If not, there may be an issue with the configuration of your Daily campaign.

Comment: Yes, I had a similar thought, and filed a request to increase the limit with AWS on August 12th, that's still in process, but they are certain that the problem is not related to it hitting the maximum limit.  They've also not found any problems with the way the Daily campaign is configured. So, I remain stuck with an ability to send out 'immediate', but not an ability to schedule.  Any other suggestions? [also, from the beginning and continuing on it works on device with immediate, but not with Daily]